# Hard to tap when running under Android 5.1

Tags: codenameone

My app works reasonably well under IOS.

Testing the app using a test device running Android 5.1 I noticed that it is hard to tap. I investigated this using a simple test program and noticed that com.codename1.ui.Display.getDragStartPercentage() always returns 1 on my test device running Android 5.1. 
In the simulator and on my IOS devices com.codename1.ui.Display.getDragStartPercentage() mostly returns 3 - only immediately after a drag-and-drop action it returns 1, which seems to be a bug.
Is this to be configured somewhere?
What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke [Display.setDragStartPercentage(3)](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#setDragStartPercentage-int-) if it makes your app feel more responsive. We don't see that behavior on Android devices so its harder for me to tell what is going on in your end.